# APIM: Limit concurrent open websocket connections

Tags: azure, websocket, azure-api-management

Is it possible to somehow limit concurrent open websocket connections (by key) in azure api management?

First attempt was using `<limit-concurrency>` in policy, but that did not work as expected, i believe it was only limiting the initial http requests instead of currently open websockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIM enforces 200 active connections limit per unit, no way to customize the limit at the moment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/websocket-api#limitations

Comment: That's what it looks like yeah. It just seems really weird that there are no policies available for that. I'm specifically trying to limit open websocket connection per _user_

Comment: The functionality will be added in future though.

Comment: Do you have any source on that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/websocket-api#limitations

Comment: i mean the "will be added in future" part :)